# How can I loop through a list in a nested list using python list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm trying to practice using list comprehensions in Python.

I set myself the task of making a list based off domino pieces that have a `5` on them. That is, the result should be:

```
[[5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6]]
```

I'm following a course, but the examples so far only show how to create these types of nested lists with ascending numbers using ranges, like `[[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]`.

I tried this code:

```
x = [val for val in range(0,7)]

Fives = [[5,x] for pieces in range(0,7)] 
print(Fives)
```

But I get a wrong result:

```
[[5, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], [5, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], [5, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], [5, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], [5, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], [5, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]], [5, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]]
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Where the code says `[[5,x] for pieces in range(0,7)]`, what do you expect this to mean? In particular: when you chose the name `pieces`, did you intend to use that somewhere else? Where it says `[5, x]`, where do you expect that `x` to come from? On the previous line, where it says `x = [val for val in range(0,7)]`, **is this intended to be helpful** for the task of creating the `[[5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6]]` list? If so, how? What is your underlying thought process there?

Comment: Anyway, please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. I edited the question to show proper style for asking a question here.

Comment: What you're calling `x` is an entire list of numbers (`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`). So, it's not surprising that the expression `[5, x]` will evaluate to `[5, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]`. You currently have two list-comprehensions in your code (one for `x`, one for `Fives`), but you only need one list-comprehension to achieve your desired result. Think about this: What you're calling `pieces` is an integer going from `0` to `6`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dangerously close to an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here!

Switching approaches, in order to create all the possible domino pieces, instead you can use [`itertools.permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

```py
>>> list(permutations(range(6+1), 2))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 6), (6, 0), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5)]
```

---

However, if instead of generating the collection directly, you must iterate through an inner list, instead iterate *over* it by directly using a form like `for value in collection:` (as all common collections are iterable - [docs on iterator and sequence types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types))

```py
values = list(range(7))  # 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
results = []
for val_upper in range(7):    # or your original list as they're the same!
    for val_lower in values:  # iterate over collection, getting each in turn
        results.append([val_upper, val_lower])
```

or when the upper (leftmost?) value is always 5 (perhaps what you really expected)

```py
>>> values = list(range(6+1))
>>> [[5, x] for x in values]  # iterates over values
[[5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6]]
```

---

Finally, if you have a small collection (as is the case here) and only wanted values that start with 5, you could comprehend your collection *back* filtering it as you go
..in this small case, it's not particularly elegant, but it's far more useful when generating a collection which isn't mathematically perfect or has specialized filtering requirements

```py
>>> list(domino for domino in permutations(range(6+1), 2) if domino[0] == 5)
[(5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Comment: It wasn't at all clear to me that OP actually wants all the domino pieces. It also seems clear from context that the goal is *specifically and explicitly* to practice using list comprehensions. (Aside from that, the kinds of things `itertools` can do are *extremely* frequently asked questions; we could dupe-hammer if that were it.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I added a little more about how they should iterate over 'em - they could also comprehend it _back_ to filter only values which start with 5

Comment: Okay, and where's the part with the *list comprehension*? "they could also comprehend it back to filter only values which start with 5" Okay, but that would be pointless, considering that a list comprehension - a simpler one - could just generate those results directly.

Comment: Not an XY problem. Quote from the top answer: *"instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y"*. But their question has both X and Y, not Y instead of X.

Comment: @KellyBundy you're right, though surely it can be debated! still, I think even though it may not be strictly True, it's valuable here and elsewhere to watch out for XY Problems .. and subtly, the crux of why their attempt fails is that it _isn't_ purely a "nested list comprehension", but a _simple_ list comprehension (which is why they find their entire collection each time)! .. and shown in example 3, they can modify their approach to come to the solution they're after! I've modified my wording to make it clearer that this is _not_ an XY Problem (..but XY Problem adjacent? ramble ramble)